# Chosing between "Office 365 Groups" and SharePoint sites inside Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, team-sites, office-365-groups

I was watching this video about "Office 365 Groups" [Office 365 Groups: Quick tour of new user and admin experiences](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SgQ1_ATw9s).

But i am not sure what are the main differences between creating "Office 365 Groups" and between creating SharePoint sites (such as Team sites and adding the related users inside the site)?? are "Office 365 Groups" and SharePoint sites suppose to replace each other? or they serve different purpose and different business needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

They are different.

Office 365 Groups is a service that works with the Office 365 tools you use already.

When you create a modern team site in Office 365, a corresponding Office 365 Group is automatically created and any users you add to your modern team site get added to the Office 365 Group. Members added to the Office 365 group associated with the site are automatically added to the site members group.

For more information about Office 365 Groups, see [Learn about Office 365 groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2).

For more information about a team site in SharePoint Online, see [Create a team site in SharePoint Online](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-team-site-in-SharePoint-Online-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d).

Comment: thanks for your reply. I already check these links, but they made me confused... mainly about these 2 main points .1)First Point, inside this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SgQ1_ATw9s they created a new "Office 365 Group", which actually create a new site similar to a SharePoint site (calendar, news feed, documents, upload videos and documents) so what is the main difference between what they did inside the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SgQ1_ATw9s and between creating a normal team site in SharePoint?

Comment: 2) second point which confused me also,is that inside this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Learn-about-Office-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2 they talk about how to create Office 365 groups, but they mentioned that one way of creating "Office 365 groups" is to create a SharePoint team site https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-team-site-in-SharePoint-Online-ef10c1e7-15f3-42a3-98aa-b5972711777d ,, is this correct ?

Comment: When we create a modern team site (not classic site) in Office 365, a corresponding Office 365 Group is automatically created. We can create Office 365 Groups from a variety of tools including Outlook, Outlook on the web, Outlook Mobile, SharePoint, Planner, Teams and more.

Comment: so you mean to create a new Office 365 group, i do not have to follow the exact steps mentioned this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SgQ1_ATw9s which directly create Office 365 group outside sharepoint?, i can simply create a new modern team site inside sharepoint, and have the office 365 group created for me? second question, can we allow end users to create modern team sites?or this functionality is for admin users only ?

Comment: Also keep in mind that there are differences in creating a “modern” Team Site (which creates an O365 group) and creating a site in SharePoint under the “root” site or under another site. Modern Team Sites are created as Site Collections (but are not listed as Site Collections in the Admin tool) and do not inherit anything from the root site like permissions, content types, etc.

Comment: @mannaggia But the confusion i am getting is that some tutorials which show how to create Office 365 groups (such as the one shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SgQ1_ATw9s) will mainly show that creating Office 365 group, will create a site with tabs for (Conversation, Files, Calendar, etc..). Also some articles is saying that creating a new Modern Team site inside sharepoint will also create new Office 365 group (if the user have permission )..

Comment: @mannaggia so now let say a user create a new modern sharepoint team site, will this mean that 2 sites will be created:- One for the Office 365 group (the site with tabs for calendar, conversations, etc..) and the other site is the Modern Team site inside sharepoint? ??

Comment: No, one site. Just a different view of it.

Comment: @mannaggia so if the customer does not have license for SharePoint online then they can not create Office 365 groups?

Answer (score 1):

@john G, no it will not create two sites - it's the same site. If you create a modern Team Site in SharePoint Online, it will create an O365 group, and if you use the Files tab in Groups and upload a file, it will appear in the Documents library in the Team Site (and vice versa).

Comment: thanks for the reply... so in this case i will have 2 sites; one for the groups itself (with file tabs, and other tabs), while the other is the modern team site with document library?? is this correct ?. For example in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SgQ1_ATw9s they create something outside sharepoint (they create a group inside office 365) , so have this operation create a modern team site inside sharepoint? or the site that have been created inside the video (the site with tabs such as conversation, calendar, and so on), is actually a modern sharepoint site?